# Won't decrypt home folder, Ubuntu server 11.04

Tags: server, encryption

I have a big problem with Ubuntu Server 11.04. When I log into the server with ssh or ftp the files in my Home folder is encrypted. This happened yesterday too, but a reboot fixed it.

I just reinstalled the OS on my desktop computer and had a backup on the server, so I need to get hold of the files.

The server has only been running for a few days and is set up using software RAID1 and has the following installed: apache2, mysql-server, munin, pure-ftpd and phpmyadmin.

I have not messed with any settings related to encryption. The only thing I have changed in terms of users is to add my user to the group www-data.

Someone here who knows how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Run `ecryptfs-mount-private`. It should be doing this automatically but until you can work out why it isn't, that should unlock your home, once you have logged in.

As for the actual issue, I've no idea why it's only running intermittently.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to reboot, but after a while the files are encrypted again.
"ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly"...what?